# Replacing the value of input tag across multiple files

Tags: php, regex, linux, sed, smarty

I have many fields in my smarty template files like this.

```
{$email} (this can be anything like -- {$description}, {$variable_name}
```

I want to replace it with  `{$email|escape:htmlall}`  or {$variable_name}

how can i do that in linux? I'm having difficulty writing regex in sed.

Comment: In `linux` OR in `PHP`?

Comment: in linux find and replace in multiple files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
sed 's/{\(\$[^}\|]*\)}/{\1|escape:htmlall}/g'
```

As a test, use:

```
echo 'blabla {$email} blieblie {$name} bloebloe ${alreadydone|escape:htmlall}'|sed 's/{\(\$[^}\|]*\)}/{\1|escape:htmlall}/gi'
```

Things that this regexp does:

- It replaces any string like {$} by {$|escape:htmlall}
- It also makes sure that two consecutive fields (as in the example) are handled separately. This is done by demanding that in the  no '}' may occur (this is done by the [^}\|]* part, which means: a series of zero or more characters which all may be anything but '}' and '|' (see below).
- It ignores any tags that already were escaped (by ignoring any tag having a | within the curly braces).

Comment: Thanks, That seems to work. is there a way to ignore variables that already have escape:htmlall like this {$email|escape:htmlall}. Currently it repeats multiple times {$email|escape:htmlall|escape:htmlall}

Comment: I edited it such that it ignores those fields that were already parsed. I did it by adding \| inside the braces I talked about earlier, meaning: "The field may contain anything but '}' and '|'.
Please accept my reply as an answer if you're happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 perl -ape 's/({\$\w+)(?!\|escape:htmlall)}/$1|escape:htmlall}/g' file
```

This is using the negative lookahead feature.

This will ignore variables that already have escape:htmlall.

Comment: Don't need to escape `)`. But you'll need to escape `{`.

Comment: hi, the values inside {} are not exactly 'email' it can be any other word like -- {email}  {description} etc..

Comment: modified to match {$anything}

Comment: This fails for a string containing multiple tags, such as

    {$email} (this can be anything like -- {$description}, {$variable_name}

Comment: perl -ape 's/({\$\w+)(?!\|escape:htmlall)}/$1|escape:htmlall}/g' file

Answer (score 0):

Make a backup before and try this:

```
grep -rl "{$email}" yourdirectory | xargs sed -i 's/\{\$email\}/{$email|escape:htmlall}/g'
```